# static / volatile in Singletons

Tags: c#

Does it make sense to make a `System.Timers.Timer` member of a singleton `volatile static`?

Would it make any difference if I make the `_fooTimer` `static` and or `volatile` in singleton instance context?

Would it make any difference if I dont make `_instance` `static`?

EDIT2: I corrected the codesample and made it now ba better Singleton without unecessary static or volatile fields and changed to Interlock.Increment

```
public sealed class Foo
{
   private static readonly object _syncRoot;

   private int _counter; 

   private Timer _fooTimer;

   private static Foo _instance;

   private Foo()
   {
       _counter = 0;
       _syncRoot = new object();
       _fooTimer = new new Timer();
       _fooTimer.Intervall = 3600000;
       _fooTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(LogFoo);
   }

   public static Foo Instance
   {
        get
        {
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                 if (_instance == null)
                 {
                      _instance = new Foo();
                 }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private void LogFoo()
    {
         // write a logfile with _counter - then restart timer and set _counter to 0
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
         Interlocked.Increment(_counter);
    }
}

public class UseTheFoo
{         
     // Foo.Instance.Increment()         

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically the *only* static variable in a singleton class is a reference to the single instance. You'd then use *instance* variables for the remaining state of the type. If you make it static then you don't even need to create a *single* instance of the class to use the timer - but I would *expect* that you'd want to do so anyway.

I'd be nervous of using `volatile`, too... it almost certainly doesn't mean exactly what you think it means.  I'd probably use [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kczs5b5.aspx) instead to achieve atomic updates to the variable.

(Note that there are plenty of better ways of implementing it, as per [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).)

EDIT: Now that the code has changed to show more members, it's a bit confusing. There's a *static* method which would use `_counter` (an instance variable) - presumably via the singleton instance. Basically, the class doesn't seem to have made up its mind about whether it wants to be a bunch of static methods, or a singleton instance. I suggest you decide and make *everything* accessible one way or the other, but not a mixture.

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for you sharing your patterns. I extendend the sample to show the usage of Foo. Btw. why the lock(_syncRoot){} should be done after checking (_instance == null) ? Is it not better to lock first?

Comment: @RobertP.: The point of the double-checked locking approach is to avoid locking unnecessarily. But that's *not* the approach I'd take. There are lots of better alternatives listed in my article :)

Comment: @RobertP.: See my edit - your class seems a bit confused at the moment.

Comment: You are right Jon, i am a little bit confused and mixed up everthing. I corrected the error with Foo.Instance

Comment: And yes, that was my issue. Make it all static or Singleton. Angain, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

By making the whole class static, you can push any thread synchronization worries during the creation of the instance to the CLR:

```
public static class Foo
{
  private static Timer _fooTimer;

  static Foo()
  {
     _fooTimer = new Timer();
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to do it the singleton way :-)

Comment: No problem, the article in Jon Skeet's answer is a great go-to for all needs singleton. That said, I haven't had a situation when just using a well-writen static class did not met my needs.